# Firefox shows I have webserver running on http://localhost:80 while other browser says "Could not connect to remote server"

Tags: server

What the hell is this ?!! Whats wrong with firefox ??!!

Intending to solve this issue I have deleted all my apache related programs from my system, though no problem is solved.

Im soo confused. Why firefox showing this wrong message ? I have checked /var/www
I have this folder as I had apache 2.2. Now I dont have any webserver though Im seeing this message.

This message is only dislayed when Im trying firefox. No other browser (opera,rekonq and chrome) showing this , instead they are returning "could not connect to localhost," which is normal message.

I have tried to figure out whether I have any other instances of apache running or not using: $ ps a | grep apache and it rerturned "command not found."

How I can be sure where that application lies ? How can I stop it ?

I dont know how much damage I already made to other programs. Is there a way I can check all program dependencies and reinstall them ?? I think I have deleted several dependent programs.

Comment: Attach the output of `dpkg -l | grep apache`

Comment: How did you "delete" Apache and the other depencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you mean that even though you have no web site running any longer, Firefox appears to show that you do.

In this case, it sounds like the issue might be Firefox keeping a local cache of your page for you.

### Step 1. Check if your site is being cached

To browse the FireFox cache and see if your site is listed as being cached, enter the following into your browser window:

> about:cache

Look around for any sign of your server or page and see if anything's there.

### Step 2. Turn of Firefox Caching

You can also ensure that the browser won't cache things by entering the settings page via entering the following into the browser window:

> about:config

and setting the "network.http.use-cache" property to "false".

### Step 3. Force a Non-cached refresh of the page in Firefox

You can do this by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> on the page to refresh it and force a get from the server. You could alternatively use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo netstat -4lptn` from a terminal window.

The output should be similar to:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1344/apache2    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1035/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1344/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      918/sshd
```

Check for anything that contains `0.0.0.0:80` and note the Process ID/name.

If you do not have a similar line, the problem is with Firefox.

Comment: Using Synaptic I have removed apache and confirmed its deletion using those above commands.

Comment: This issue is fixed. I was having that issue due to two addons: One is "session manager" and the other is "tab mix plus."

I cleaned my firefox's cache and cookies and the problem is gone. Session manager have kept a cached verion of that page I viewed earliar.

Comment: Good to hear that! Now I suggest you to add your comment as an answer and accept it, because it solved your problem. (Or accept goober's because it is more Firefox-related than mine and following that would have pointed out the cached page...)